# Solve Function is not Working in Follwing Program

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

My Solve Function is not working and I don't know what is wrong with my Code.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**Program Required Output:**
Solve: This function will take a polynomial and a variable as input. It will solve the
polynomial for given value of variable and will return computed result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void Input(int terms, int deg[], int coef[])
{
    int temp = 0;
    cout << "Enter Terms = ";
    cin >> terms;
    cout << "Enter Degrees in Descending Order = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        cin >> deg[i];
        int temp = deg[i];
        if (deg[i] > 15)
        {
            cout << "Enter the Degree again (must be less tham 15) = ";
            cin >> deg[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
        {
            if (deg[i] < deg[i+1])
            {
                temp = deg[i];
                deg[i] = deg[i+1];
                deg[i+1] = temp;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    cout << "Enter Coefficients = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        cin >> coef[i];
    }
}

int Solve(int terms, int deg[], int coef[], int variable)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int result;
    cout << "Enter Variable = ";
    cin >> variable;
    Input(terms, deg, coef);

    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        result = pow(variable,deg[i]);
        sum = result * coef[i];
        sum = sum + result;
        cout << result;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int terms = 0;
    int deg[5] = {0,0,0,0,0}; 
    int coef[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int var = 0;
    Solve(terms, deg, coef, var);
}
```

**OUTPUT I AM, GETTING:**

```
Enter Variable = 2
Enter Terms = 3 
Enter Degrees in Descending Order = 3 2 1 
Enter Coefficients = 2 2 2 
0
```

Comment: Looks like in `Solve()` the variable `terms` is always 0 because you pass it by value to `Input()`

Comment: Any Possible Solution for it ?

Comment: Pass by reference instead of by value. Remember passing by value passes a copy of the variable into the function.

Comment: Ok. Let me try. Thanks mate

Comment: If you don't know `void Input(int & terms, int deg[], int coef[])` is the fix.

Comment: There is an additional problem. The size of your arrays is 5. So you check that terms is 1 to 5.

Comment: `if (deg[i] < deg[i+1])` will potentially cause an out of bounds access of your arrays.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 2):

Correct Solution 
Thanks to @drescherjm

```
void Input(int &terms, int deg[], int coef[])
{
    int temp = 0;
    cout << "Enter Terms = ";
    cin >> terms;
    cout << "Enter Degrees in Descending Order = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        cin >> deg[i];
        int temp = deg[i];
        if (deg[i] > 15)
        {
            cout << "Enter the Degree again (must be less tham 15) = ";
            cin >> deg[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
        {
            if (deg[i] < deg[i+1])
            {
                temp = deg[i];
                deg[i] = deg[i+1];
                deg[i+1] = temp;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    cout << "Enter Coefficients = ";
    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        cin >> coef[i];
    }
}

int Solve(int terms, int deg[], int coef[], int variable)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int result;
    cout << "Enter Variable = ";
    cin >> variable;
    Input(terms, deg, coef);

    for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        int calc;
        result = pow(variable,deg[i]);
        calc = result * coef[i];
        sum = sum + calc;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int terms = 0;
    int deg[5] = {0,0,0,0,0}; 
    int coef[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int var = 0;
    Solve(terms, deg, coef, var);
}
```